# Question about the proof that $C^b$ is complete with sup norm.

Tags: real-analysis

It is a proof from Chapter 4.1, Pugh's real mathematical analysis. $C^b$ stands for the set of all bounded functions $[a,b]\to \mathcal R$ and we use sup-norm here.

The proof he gave is as follow.

Let $f_n$ be Cauchy in $C^b$. Let $f(x)=lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$. Want to show $f_n$ uniformly convergent to $f$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$.$\exists N$ such that $m,n>N \implies d(f_n,f_m)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ since it is Cauchy.

Also for each $x\in [a,b]$, $\exists m=max(m(x),N)$ such that $d(f_m(x),f(x))<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Then for $x\in [a,b]$, $d(f_n(x),f(x))\leq d(f_n(x),f_{m_(x)}(x))+d(f_{m(x)},f(x))<\epsilon$

Also, $f$ is clearly in $C^b$. So we are done

But prof. Pugh remarked that the proof is subtle since the uniform convergence is derived by non-uniform means. It is a case of the ends justifying the means.

I understand that it is derived by non-uniform means, but what does he mean for the last sentence. And how can we deal with this subtle problem?

Answer (score 0):

The last sentence means that in an intermediate step (the means), an x-dependent quantity is introduced, which seems to violate the spirit of uniformity, but in the end this x-dependence does not show up.

What happens about this subtety is that the function $f_m$ is introduced by us and we have the freedom to determine what m is. We are choosing the n such that $d(f_n, f)$ is small, not m. The x-dependence of m does not matter as long as it does not intervene the choice of n. Indeed, the N chosen in the proof yields from the uniform Cauchyness of ${f_n}$ which definitely is x-independent.

The means of introducing an x-dependent quantity does not produce an x-dependent end.